# How to clear the content from a listproxy

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How do I clear a shared multiprocess manager.list? In the example below, I want to clear it before the loop continues so that the new spawned processes find an empty list.

```
num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() 
p = multiprocessing.Pool(num_consumers)
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
mp_list = manager.list()

def put_some_data(data):
    #Processing occurs and then we append the result
    mp_list.append(data)

def do_some_processing():
    While True:
        #Multiprocessing runs here
        result = p.map(put_some_data, data)
        mp_list.clear()
        #When done, break
```

The above throws the error `AttributeError: 'ListProxy' object has no attribute 'clear'`

The [documentation is not very clear](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects)() on how one can clear the proxylist object

Comment: Could you just make it a new list?

Comment: I tried that even before posting the question but it seemed that If I declare a new list in the `def do_some_processing`, the spawned processes do not see it when they call the `def put_some_data` function. The `put_some_data` function seems to only see the globally declared `mp_list`

Comment: I've adopted the Queue as suggested below -especially after @brian-cain chipped in- and marked that as the answer but am wondering if its just not possible to clear a multiprocess manager.list? Surely there must be a way that is quick and efficient

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is the way I do it. List comprehension to the rescue!

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> m = multiprocessing.Manager()
>>> lst = m.list()
>>> lst.append(0)
>>> lst.append(1)
>>> lst.append(2)
>>> lst
<ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0x3397970>
>>> lst[:]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> lst[:] = [] 
>>> lst
<ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0x3397970>
>>> lst[:]
[]
>>>
```

so

```
>>> lst[:] = []
```

does it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference

```
del mp_list[:]
```

and

```
mp_list *= 0
```

also works but the accepted answer is probably the cleanest solution.